# Angular Http Client Rest Api Delete Request

Tags: angular, httpclient, rest

Currently, i'm learning http request module in Angular.
My problem is why the error didn't occur and still get deleted even the request id delete is out the list of data.

```
deletePost(x) {
this.s.deleteInfo(33).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  let index = this.post.indexOf(x);
  this.post.splice(index, 1);
},(error:Response)=>{
  if(error.status ==404){
    alert("Expected Error!");
    console.log("hello")
  }
});
```

[image: Fake Rest Api Call]

As we can see there is only 6 data displayed on the console, but i can still delete with the id of 33

Comment: Could you share your this.s service? And maybe share the network error. (To check network errors, you will have to look for them in the devtools, using the Network tab) Whenever you work with back-front communication try to have this tab open to see what's your backend answering.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your request was successful.

Here to achieve the functionality you want you need to do something like below:

```
if(this.post.indexOf(33) == -1){
    alert("Expected Error!");
}
else{
    console.log('Hurray!')
}
```

Or if you are not doing it, you can catch error in your service like below:

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

```
errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
   return Observable.throw(error.message || "server error.");
}
this.http.get(this.url).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
```